A counterexample for $abH \neq baH$ even if $H$ is normal
Suppose $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, which is to say $aH=Ha$. I want to find a counterexample such that $abH \neq baH$.
I have tried that if $ab \in H$, then $abH=baH$, since $ab=h$ implies that $ba=bhb^{-1} \in H$ where the last belonging to $H$ comes from the normal premise.
But what would happen if $ab \notin H$, $abH$ may stay in one left coset and $ba$ another. But I can't find a exmaple to support my thought.
Thank you inadvance.

Just take $H$ to be trivial.

@QiaochuYuan Wow, that's elegant enough. Intuitively the normal group must be large enough, so when testing normal subgroup I find large order. I can't think it is so trivial to prove it. Thanks.

@MartinBrandenburg I'm not persuaded that the question you linked to is a duplicate. This one essentially asks "can $G/H$ ever be nonabelian?" and the other asks "can $G/H$ ever be abelian when $G$ itself is nonabelian?"

@MartinBrandenburg You specifically linked to an answer that describes how $Q_8/K_4\cong C_2$. But OP asks for $G/H$ to be nonabelian. The answer you linked to is not answering this question, a side effect of that question being different (although related) to OP.

Yes that specific answer is not a duplicate, sorry for that. The question is, though.

@MartinBrandenburg I disagree. Have you read the body of that question? "But is there cases when this quotient group is abelian without the group G being abelian?" This will be my last comment about the matter though.

Take any nonabelian group $G$ with a normal subgroup $H$ such that $G/H$ is still nonabelian.
For example $Q_8\times H$ for any group $H$.

Wow. Thanks for a nontrivial example.

Instead of answering duplicates, it would be better to look for a good duplicate target. Please also read the meta announcement regarding quality standards.

The questions are related but not duplicates. This one essentially asks "can $G/H$ ever be nonabelian?" and the other asks "can $G/H$ ever be abelian when $G$ itself is nonabelian?"

The linked dupe gives a general condition when G/H is abelian and hence answers the question.
